# Construct choice functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, axiom-of-choice

Can someone review my solution for the following exercise?

Construct a choice function for

1. All nonempty finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$
2. All nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$

**Solution:**

2.

$A \in \{X: X \subset \mathbb{Z}\} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$

$f(A) =
\begin{cases}
\min\{x:x\in A\},  & \forall x \in A:x>0 \\
\max\{x:x\in A\}, & \forall x \in A:x<0 \\
0, & 0 \in A \\
\min\{\vert x \vert: x\in A\}, & \text{else} 
\end{cases}$

1.

$A \in \{X: X \subset \mathbb{R}, \# A < \infty \} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$

$f(A)=\min\{x:x \in A\}$

Comment: Between the problem and the solution, you seem to have swapped 1 and 2.

Comment: The first case is $\forall x\in A:x\gt0$ and the second case is . . . the same? Did you want $x\lt0$ in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is not entirely correct. If $A=\{-1,2\}$ then $f(A)=1$ as you define it, but $1\notin A$.

Instead, you can compress all the cases into a correctly formed $$f(A)=\min\{x\in A:|x|=\min\{|x|:x\in A\}\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The definition in 1. is ambiguous. What is $f(\{0,1,2,4\})$? $1$ as the first clause says or $4$ as the second says, or $0$ as the third says?

2. is fine (we could also use the max).